# An integral formula

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

What is the general formual of definite integral of $\sin^n(x)$ from $0$ to $\pi$ ?
Here, $n$ is any natural number.

I'm studying quantum mechanics and this kind of integral appears frequently. So, I hope to know the general formula.

Comment: You will find everything you need in this article : [Wallis's integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *C.R.C. Mathematical Tables, Thirteenth edition*, gives half this integral, as the integral of $\sin^n x$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So adapting that, your integral is

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}\sin^n x\,dx & =  \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots (n-1)}
 {2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (n)}\cdot\pi,\quad\text{[$n$ an even integer]} \\
& =  \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6 \cdots (n-1)}
 {1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots (n)}\cdot 2,\quad\text{[$n$ an odd integer]} \\
& =  \sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{n+1}2 \right)}
 {\Gamma\left( \frac n2+1 \right)},\quad [n>-1] \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your information